# sqlite flask table not showing up

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

When I run my code and connect to my local host and add a task to my todo list. I go back to my code and run the terminal and enter the code  >> sqlite3 database.db then >> select * from todo; and the error message im getting is that there is >> no such table : todo(1). I don't understand why im getting the error message even after manually creating the db and table within the code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = ' 43235a0c23c2457e96417f2de3c292df '

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Creating the Todo model
class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    todo = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

# Initializing the database and creating the table if it doesn't exist
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

# Initializing the TodoForm
class TodoForm(FlaskForm):
    todo = StringField("Enter Todo", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=50)])
    submit = SubmitField('Add Todo')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', "POST"])
def home():
    form = TodoForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_todo = Todo(todo=form.todo.data)
        db.session.add(new_todo)
        db.session.commit()
        
    todos = Todo.query.all()
    return render_template("home.html", form=form, todos=todos)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I added this line of code thinking it will manually create the db

with app.app_context():
db.create_all()

Comment: It's possible that you create a `database.db`, just not where you expected. URIs are finicky for sqlite3. See https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/blob/v0.4/config.py#L8 for an example of setting one up.

Comment: Thank you ! I’m going to check it out asap , would u reccomend something else other than sqlite3?

Comment: It depends. sqlite3 is an excellent choice for many projects, but it doesn't have a great schema migration story. If you're going to be in a situation where you need to evolve the schema over time, I'd look at PostgreSQL or MySQL.